# How to turn off text in Special Widget Instagram Feed Theme Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes, instagram

I am having issues with one of my theme's plugin.

The Instagram feed widget for the sidebar is showing text of my Instagram post. Weird fact is that's only for the post I promoted on Instagram.

The page I have problem with : https://dermelia.fr/epilation-laser/epilation-laser-un-acte-medical/

Here is the code of the plugin :

[image: Code of my plugin]

I can't find anything about text import in the code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your code instead of posting an image of code.  Reference:  ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/8239061), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385521/8239061))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is send through the instagram API, which means you can't edit it in the plugin code. You could fix it though. With css you could easily hide the text as follows:

```
ul.eltdf-instagram-feed li a {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height:0;
}
```